# Поиск по сайту, на странице поиска в Google

Tags: веб-программирование, google-search

Интересует, как реализовать поиск по сайту прямо на странице выдачи в поисковой системе Google?

Пример: [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это реализовывается с помощью специальной разметки на целевом сайте.

- [**Sitelinks Search Box**](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/richsnippets/sitelinkssearch)
- [**How To Setup Google Sitelink Search**](http://www.seocandy.co.uk/seo/setup-google-sitelink-search/)

Comment: Большое спасибо, долго не мог загуглить как это называеться!